# Richardson extrapolation of 4th order Runge-Kutta

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I want to find the Richardson extrapolation of the 4th order Runga-Kutta method. I found a formula on Wikipedia for a general approximation and then I tried applying it to the specific method. I got this:

$A=A(h)+kh^4+O(h^{5})$

I know that the local truncation error is proportional to $h^5$ which is why I chose the last term to be of that order. For the other step size I get:

$A=A(h/2)+k(h/2)^4+O(h^{5})$

Then I can multiply the first equation by 16 and subtract the second equation and get:

$15A=16A-A=16A(h/2)-A(h)+15O(h^5)$

Dividing by 15, I finally get:

$A=\frac{16}{15}A(\frac{h}{2})-\frac{1}{15}A(h)+O(h^5)$

But is this the right way to do the extrapolation? I am not sure how to interpret the term $kh^4$. Does this term belong to the approximation or the error?

Comment: I don't think it helps me. They seem to discuss Richardson extrapolation for two different steps? So there are four steps in total? It is a bit confusion. Sorry.

Comment: And why is the error term of order O(h^6) and not O(h^5) in the post you referred to?

Comment: There are 3 RK4 steps involved, two for $h/2$ and one for $h$. The error expansion is for the local error. These details are missing/implicit in your calculation. Which is correct as far as presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare 2 approximations for the exact value $y(t)=A=A(0)$ at some time $t=nh$ starting from the same point $y(0)=y_0$ (shift the actual times as necessary).

- $A(h)$ is computed with $n$ steps of step size $h$ and
- $A(h/2)$ is computed with $2n$ steps with step size $h/2$

The multi-step approximation global error has indeed the formula
$$
A=A(h)+kh^4+O(h^5)
$$
and all your calculations follow. The two integrations together result in $3n$ RK4 steps. (Note that the Fehlberg method, as fixed-step method, gives order 5 in 6 steps, which is also the average step count for the RK4 extrapolation if seen as method with step size $h/2$.)

In the linked answer the case $n=1$ is considered, that is, $t=h$. The error coefficient $k=k(t)$ is initially mostly linear in $t$, $k=k_1t+O(t^2)$, so that the error formula gains another factor $h$.
$$
A=A(h)+\underbrace{(k_1t)}_{=k_1h=constant}·h^4+O(h^6)
$$